# SwipeRefreshLayout with OverScrollView

Tags: android

I want to ask, how can I implement SwipeRefreshLayout with OverScrollView like the one in this application example.

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcyIw.jpg)

Comment: do you want swiperefresh like instagram

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.